# 10054 & SSL errors from non-Indy client to Indy Server (kbmMWTCPIPIndyServerTransport)

Tags: http, delphi, mobile, indy

We have a kbmMW server that uses an Indy TCPIP Server Transport behind the scenes. We have a server that is currently in testing with a mobile client that is under development.

Overall everything is working pretty well, but we occasionally get 10054's EIdSocketExceptions and EIdSSLExceptions. This appears to be just normal TCPIP 'cost of doing business'. Unfortunately it is occurring in non-VCL main threads and it is crashing the server.

Our goal is to simply know where, when and how to gracefully handle these errors so that it doesn't crash the server.

I've included madExcept logs below:

thread $19c0 (TIdThreadWithTask), inner exception level 1:

> > EIdSocketError, Socket Error # 10054
> >     Connection reset by peer.
> >     0146005b +073 icms.exe     IdStack                         929 +54 TIdStack.RaiseSocketError
> >     0145ffe2 +016 icms.exe     IdStack                         852  +1 TIdStack.RaiseLastSocketError
> >     0145ff4d +015 icms.exe     IdStack                         826  +2 TIdStack.CheckForSocketError
> >     014587c5 +02d icms.exe     IdStackBSDBase                  440  +1 TIdStackBSDBase.Receive
> >     014960b1 +011 icms.exe     IdSocketHandle                  319  +1 TIdSocketHandle.Receive
> >     0149a0ee +006 icms.exe     IdIOHandlerStack                378  +0 TIdIOHandlerStack.ReadDataFromSource
> >     014a5f8d +009 icms.exe     IdSSL                           180  +1 TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase.ReadDataFromSource
> >     01493005 +0e5 icms.exe     IdIOHandler                    1688 +28 TIdIOHandler.ReadFromSource
> >     01499ccb +00b icms.exe     IdIOHandlerStack                232  +1 TIdIOHandlerStack.Connected
> >     0149ec43 +013 icms.exe     IdTCPConnection                 503  +3 TIdTCPConnection.Connected
> >     0198dc4f +117 icms.exe     kbmMWTCPIPIndyServerTransport   353 +18 TkbmMWCustomTCPIPIndyServerTransport.OnExecute
> >     014a46ec +018 icms.exe     IdCustomTCPServer               553  +2 TIdCustomTCPServer.DoExecute
> >     014a0f63 +00f icms.exe     IdContext                       185  +2 TIdContext.Run
> >     0149fafe +002 icms.exe     IdTask                          136  +0 TIdTask.DoRun
> >     014a21e6 +006 icms.exe     IdThread                        697  +1 TIdThreadWithTask.Run
> >     014a1ba1 +0f5 icms.exe     IdThread                        428 +50 TIdThread.Execute
> >     00545489 +049 icms.exe     System.Classes                14701 +18 ThreadProc
> >     0040cbf4 +028 icms.exe     System                        23825 +45 ThreadWrapper
> >     004b327d +00d icms.exe     madExcept                               CallThreadProcSafe
> >     004b32e2 +032 icms.exe     madExcept                               ThreadExceptFrame
> >     77587c02 +022 KERNEL32.DLL                                         BaseThreadInitThunk
> >     014a1da2 +052 icms.exe     IdThread                        522 +24 TIdThread.Create

Also:

Details: Error accepting connection with SSL.
error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher

Details: Error accepting connection with SSL.
error:1408A10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:wrong version number

Details: Error accepting connection with SSL.
EOF was observed that violates the protocol

Details: Error accepting connection with SSL.
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Thanks!

Comment: The errors don't "crash the server". They are perfectly normal exceptions that happen during failed TCP/SSL operations within the Indy server's own worker threads (`TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component) and as such the server will handle them internally for you. The only way you would ever see them is if you are catching them manually in code, or running your server app in the debugger. And BTW, your stack trace implies your `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` handler is calling `TIdTCPConnection.Connected()` directly, which it really should not be doing.

Comment: Sorry about the 'crash the server' comment, I should have been more specific. We have a kbmMW application server which internally uses the TIdTCPServer. And yes, because of the way that we deal with 'unhandled' exceptions, it does 'crash the server'.

Comment: If you were going to trap for these errors, where would you do it? At what point of execution? How to handle gracefully?

Comment: "*because of the way that we deal with 'unhandled' exceptions, it does 'crash the server'*" - in what way exactly do you handle them? What do you consider to be a "crash" exactly? What is the actual problem that you are experiencing? Please [edit] your question to be more specific. Like I said, `TIdTCPServer` should be handling these errors for you, so it can close the sockets and clean up the SSL objects and managing threads.

Comment: One thing that I noticed is that in regard to the SSL errors, we had placed an exception handler that logs an error message to file in the OnConnect transport event. Since the logging method executes in the VCL main thread and was not specifically made thread safe, that may be responsible for the SSL errors/problems. Still digging